# Why does python's re.search method hang?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python regex library to parse some strings and currently I found that my regex is either too complicated or the string I'm searching is too long.

Here's an example of the hang up:

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = "(\w+'?\s*)+[-|~]\s*((\d+\.?\d+\$?)|(\$?\d+\.?\d+))"
>>> re.search(reg, "**LOOKING FOR PAYPAL OFFERS ON THESE PAINTED UNCOMMONS**") #Hangs here...
```

I'm not sure what's going on. Any help appreciated!

EDIT: Here's a link with examples of what I'm trying to match: [Regxr](http://regexr.com/3fnbo)

Comment: What are you trying to search for?

Comment: You have catastrophic backtracking. https://regex101.com/r/0vq6T7/1

Comment: As usual, catastrophic backtracking due to one obligatory and optional patterns inside a quantified group `(\w+'?\s*)+`. What do you want to match with it? Try changing it to `(\w+(?:'\s*\w+)*)`

Comment: I updated my question with an example of what I'm trying to match. @Keatinge thank you. I'll look into catastrophic backtracking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why the code execution hangs is [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) due to one obligatory and 1+ optional patterns (those that can match an empty string) inside a quantified group `(\w+'?\s*)+` that allows a regex engine to test a lot of matching paths, so many that it takes too long to complete.

I suggest unwrapping the problematic group in such a way that `'` or `\s` become obligatory and wrap them in an optional group:

```
(\w+(?:['\s]+\w+)*)\s*[-~]\s*(\$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$?)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^***
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0yEMy/1)

Here, `(\w+(?:['\s]+\w+)*)` will match 1+ word chars, and then 0+ sequences of 1+ `'` or whitespaces followed with 1+ word chars. This way, the pattern becomes linear and the regex engine fails the match quicker if a non-matching string occurs.

The rest of the pattern:

- `\s*[-~]\s*`  - either `-` or `~` wrapped with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$?)` - Group 2 capturing

  - `\$?` - 1 or 0 `$` symbols
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - 1 or 0 zero sequences of:

    - `\.` - a dot
    - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\$?` - 1 or 0 `$` symbols

Comment: Thank you! I built this regex from scratch so I was afraid it wasn't going to be robust. I'm still a bit confused on lookarounds though. I see you added one. What's the difference between that and what I had before?

Comment: There are no lookarounds in the pattern I suggested. Just capturing and non-capturing groups and quantifiers. There should be no big difference, just `\$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\$?` can match `$15$`, but I doubt it will happen. You may use your `(?:(\d+\.?\d+\$?)|(\$?\d+\.?\d+))` if you find that "shortcut" matches "too much".

Comment: Yes, that is a [non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) used only to group subpatterns, not to create `.group()`s.

Comment: After reading that thread, I realize that I've been using the words match and capture interchangeably. From what I've read, matching will not "return" something and capture does.

Comment: This answer opened my eyes that behind the scene some logic is running and it is not like you write any valid regular expression and that is it. A simple unwrapping suggested here helped my re.search() to be up and running :)